# parse_args do not include None values in Namespace

Tags: python, argparse, nonetype

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('-x')
parser.add_argument('--foo')
ns = parser.parse_args(['-x', 'X'])  # Namespace(foo=None, x='X')
```

Is there any way to have `parse_args` avoid including None values in the returned Namespace? So that

```
vars(ns) == {k:v for k,v in vars(ns).items() if v is not None}
```

without doing it manually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes, add `argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS` ([full doc](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/argparse.html#argument-default))

> to globally suppress attribute creation on parse_args() calls, we supply argument_default=SUPPRESS:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG',argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('-x')
parser.add_argument('--foo')
ns = parser.parse_args(['-x', 'X'])
```

now:

```
>>> ns
Namespace(x='X')
```